# Вывод данных с консоли в окно pygame или tkinter

Tags: python, tkinter, pygame

как в окно tkinter или pygame выводить данные с консоли?

Comment: Определитесь, куда конкретно нужно выводить - в окно pygame или в tkinter. И что за данные с консоли.

Comment: @insolor rkinter

Comment: @insolor все деннае которые выводит принт

Comment: Заменяете print на вывод в виджеты tkinter. Смешивать print с tkinter не нужно.